# jq possible to use has() with nested keys?

Tags: nested, key, jq

is it possible to use the jq has() function with nested keys

```
jq -r -c 'has("a.b")' <<< '{"a":{"b":"hello"}}'
```

this returns as false, I have also tried

```
has("a|b")
has("a[b]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can descend to that level, and use `has` for the last one:

```bash
jq '(.a | has("b"))' <<< '{"a":{"b":"hello"}}'
```

Alternatively, search the `paths` for the one you are looking for, converted to array notation:

```bash
jq 'IN(paths; ["a","b"])' <<< '{"a":{"b":"hello"}}'
```

Comment: excellent choices, `paths` looks like the best replacement, thanks pmf!

Comment: @artvanderlay You can also generate the array notation using `path(.a.b)` which produces `["a","b"]` (note that here `.a.b` is not a string but a direct path expression, thus starting with a dot).

Answer (score 1):

Since computing `paths` can be quite time-consuming, it’s worth knowing that if you simply want to know whether .a.b is defined and non-null, you could use `getpath/1`, either by itself or wrapped in an `if`, e.g.

```
getpath(["a","b"]) | if . == null then false else true end
```